# MySQL 8 AES_ENCRYPT() & AES_DECRYPT(). Correct inplementation?

Tags: mysql, encryption

I would like to know the proper implementation of AES_ENCRYPT & AES_DECRYPT in MySQL 8.

I have a table with fields `ownerId`VARCHAR(16) & `ownerPassword`(BLOB).

**1. We insert a record into table** `01_tblCompany` using the MySQL `AES_ENCRYPT()` function to encrypt the `ownerPassword` field like this:

```
INSERT INTO 01_tblCompany (ownerId, ownerPassword) VALUES ('owner001', AES_ENCRYPT('password123', 'privateKey'));
```

**2. We select this record from table** `01_tblCompany` using the MySQL `AES_DECRYPT()` function to decrypt the `ownerPassword` field like this:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(ownerPassword, 'privateKey') AS ownerPassword FROM 01_tblCompany WHERE ownerId = 'owner001';
```

The [MySQL page for the AES Encryption function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt)  states that you shouldn't just hand a plain text privateKey to the `key_str` argument  and that

> the most secure way to pass a key to the key_str argument is to create
>   a truly random 128-bit value and pass it as a binary value.

I think that's about the time my hair started to smoke and I was hoping someone could show a full example of the correct implementation?

Comment: use the example at further on the page. it has all you need

Answer (score 1):

Alright. This is how we insert and select a field using `AES_ENCRYPT()` & `AES_DECRYPT()` using MySQL's default `block_encryption_mode`, `aes-128-ecb`.

The `block_encryption_mode` variable controls the **block encryption mode**.

The default setting is `aes-128-ecb`. ECB mode is useful for databases because it doesn't require an IV, and therefore there is a 1:1 ciphertext:plaintext relationship.

**Notice that we never really use** `AES_DECRYPT()` to decrypt the password stored in the database. You should have zero knowledge of a user's password.

**We instead, encrypt a user's input attempt at a correct password.**

**If both encrypted values match**, then we have a successful login.

```
/* ANALYSIS */
SELECT SHA2('privateKey',512);
SELECT LENGTH(SHA2('privateKey',512));
SELECT UNHEX(SHA2('privateKey',512));
SELECT LENGTH(UNHEX(SHA2('privateKey',512)));

/* INSERT ONWER */
INSERT INTO 01_tblCompany (ownerId, ownerPassword) VALUES ('owner001', AES_ENCRYPT('password123', UNHEX(SHA2('privateKey',512))));

/* SELECT ONWER */
SELECT ownerId, ownerPassword FROM 01_tblCompany WHERE ownerId = 'owner001' AND ownerPassword = AES_ENCRYPT('password123', UNHEX(SHA2('privateKey',512)));

/* INSERT USER */
INSERT INTO 02_tblCompanyUsers (ownerId, userName, userPassword) VALUES ('owner001', 'user001', AES_ENCRYPT('password123', UNHEX(SHA2('privateKey',512))));

/* SELECT USER */
SELECT ownerId, userName, userPassword FROM 02_tblCompanyUsers WHERE userName = 'user001' AND userPassword = AES_ENCRYPT('password123', UNHEX(SHA2('privateKey',512)));
```

Comment: Beware that this is not a correct way of validating a user's password. When performed correctly a password hash (using PBKDF, bcrypt or Argon2 algorithms) is used. Using ECB on passwords is dangerous as it leaks identical blocks and thus information about (partially) identical passwords. Storing a key into SQL queries is dangerous as well. You may not decrypt, but what keeps an adversary from decryption of the password?

Comment: I like what you have to say. So, AES CBC? I'm currently using a Digital Ocean Managed Database but it appears changing the default `block_encryption_mode` cannot be executed with an admin account. I've read that CBC is more computationally intensive but this will only ever happen during login. The `privateKey` can be inserted into the query using php include, guessing the IV as well?